# Is encapsulation in Swift as important as in other OO languages

Tags: ios, swift, encapsulation

When I was learning other languages such as Java, all the sample code tells you that you should always mark a field `private`. And the methods that do the internal stuff are also marked `private` or `protected`.

But when it comes to Swift, I see that the sample code from a lot of the tutorials (such as raywenderlich.com) seldom marks something as `private`. They just leave it `internal` (without adding any modifiers).

In contrast, all the android tutorials mark some of the fields as `private` and provide no getters or setters for them.

For example, I read this search bar tutorial a while ago:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

When I was reading through it, I was thinking about: "Why did you not mark this `private`?"

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

I mean, it does not make sense for other classes to access the search controller of *my* VC. It's *mine*!

Question:

Why don't most, if not all tutorials provide sample code that contains private properties? Is it because iOS is more secure or something? Should I mark suitable stuff as private in production code?

I hope this is not too opinion based. In Java, you will never make a field public, right? That's just a fact - you should not make fields public. So please don't close as opinion based, it's not.

Comment: In general, anything that is not `internal` should be marked as `private` or even `public`. This is for the same reason as in any other language and it helps enforce your app design / object graph through the compiler.  Similarly for the `final` modifier for classes. My personal view is that tutorials should also do this but whether the tutorial does or does not is really down to their viewpoint on example code. So their "opinion" and style, in other words.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as Primarily Opinion-Based because answers can only be based on opinion, not fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not everything private? There are several really common scenarios that I've seen that always favor having the variable either internal or public.

Delegate methods:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(
        myCellID,
        forIndexPath: indexPath);
    return cell;
}
```

This method will be called not internally by you, but rather by the iOS system that manages and displays the tableView. The delegation pattern is widely used within iOS development.

Data exchange between two ViewControllers, where you simply want to set the other ViewController's field:

```
class MyVC1: UIViewController {

   var flagShouldUpateColors = false {
      didSet{ 
            // some stuff
      }
   }


}
```

Then at some point you want to notifiy this ViewController that the flag should be set to true. You do that my simply acccessing it's field.

Also selectors. When I register an instance of a ViewController for some notification, I pass the name of a method that I have within the very same  ViewController. It is to be called when the notification triggers. Basically what the code says is "please call this method for me when this occurs". If you say call this *private* method when this occurs, it wouldn't make sense would it ? How is the caller supposed to call it(aside from reflection and other unoptimized ways). Here is example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.doStuffWhenEnterForeground),
        name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification,
        object: app)
    doStuffWhenEnterForeground();
}
func doStuffWhenEnterForeground() {

}
```

Comment: So other than these three things, all stuff should be private. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I gotta go to sleep now, I'll accept tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Main difference between Java and Swift is in properties.

Java has no concept of properties. It has fields and if you want to allow public access to those fields you can either access them directly or through getter/setter methods.

If you create public field that needs to be protected later on you will have to use methods and thus your public API will be changed - fields are accessed without parens and methods with them.

Swift is different in that regard. You can protect your field access with getter/setter at any point without changing API. So if you have field that is part of public API you can just leave it as is (without making it private) and without having getter/setter methods attached to it.

Encapsulation in Java and Swift are of the same importance. What differs is how it is achieved (implemented). Since there is no pressure for *premature encapsulation* in Swift and it is only matter of adding visibility specifier when appropriate there is some *lack of discipline* in adding those in tutorial code where main purpose is not enforcing encapsulation, but teaching some other concepts and how-to's.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't most, if not all tutorials provide sample code that contains private properties? Is it because iOS is more secure or something? Should I mark suitable stuff as private in production code?

Probably because it's simpler, save few keystrokes and doesn't add unnecessary overhead to understanding the main theme of tutorial.

> Should I mark suitable stuff as private in production code?

Yes, you should do it for the same reasons you would do it in Java. Notice 2 things, however:

1. There is no such thing as `protected`.
2. Access modifiers in Swift work differently compared to many other languages. `private` restricts access to variable or function to file where it was declared, *regardless of who will access them*. Thus, if you have 2 classes declared in the same file, they both can see private fields of each other. On the other hand, you can't see private fields even from extension of that class if this extension in other file. It looks strange at first and you just need to get used to it.